# Is there a way to start a jar file hidden?

Tags: java, jar, hidden

I have a .jar file that I would like to run hidden in the background every time I start my computer. I use `javaw -jar x.jar` to load it but I can't seem to find a way to start it hidden. Is there a way?

Comment: The answer will depend on the operating system. Please specify.

Comment: `javaw` is a strong hint that the system is Windows.

Comment: How is it not hidden now? Are you seeing a "black window" when it starts up, or is there a GUI? Or is it a problem that the program shows up in the task bar?

Comment: Oh sorry. The system is Windows 7 64-bit and yes, there is a GUI. So is there a way to start it hidden so that it wouldn't display the GUI.

Comment: Unless you are willing to modify code and rebuild the jar, this really isn't a programming question.

Comment: @Janne A, the application would need to be designed to be run GUI-less

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend running the application as a Windows Service. You can use a service "wrapper" as suggested by Romain.

Alternatively, you can use Tomcat. Tomcat for Windows includes two binaries, tomcat.exe and tomcatw.exe.

tomcat.exe can be used to install your app as a Windows Service while tomcatw.exe can be used to configure said service.

These binaries used to be included with the Apache Commons Daemon project as something called "procrun." However, I think the project may be defunct. The documentation still exists though. Here is a link:
http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html

I've been able to use this approach with some success. I can probably provide some more information if you have questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

Look here, you can run as a Service: http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

Comment: Initially voted up, but removed that when Janne clarified that it has a GUI.  Running as a service would not allow the GUI to be seen.

Comment: @Alan Krueger - He does not want the GUI to be seen

Comment: @Janne Were you looking for "never visible" or "initially hidden"? Running a GUI as a service doen't make a lot of sense; why have a GUI at all?